# moduli space of triangles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, triangles, moduli-space

I found an article which seems to be aimed for general audience. I couldn't understand sentences about triangles. The link to the article is the following.
http://www.abelprize.no/c57681/artikkel/vis.html?tid=57787.

The author mentions the moduli space of triangles, up to similarity. I interpret symmetries there as isometries of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Non-trivial symmetries of equilateral triangles over the circle seems to be the 1/3-rotation around the center of the triangle.

Now I don't understand the sentence *The image of the family into the universal family is constant, since the triangle is the same for all points in the circle*. It seems to me that triangles are not the same. I thought the universal family is the space of triangles before equivalence. Am I misunderstanding what universal family is? And what does it mean to say that the family doesn't contain some other family?

I have a trouble in understanding moduli spaces and this simple-looking example confuses me even more.

Comment: The article link is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought the universal family is the space of triangles before equivalence.

No, the universal family is supposed to be a family (over the moduli space) which contains every isomorphism (i.e. similarity) class exactly once. More precisely, if $M$ is the moduli space and $U$ is the universal family, there is a map

$$ \pi: U \rightarrow M$$

such that for a point $p \in M$, the fibre $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is a triangle in the isomorphism class $p$.

Up to similarity there is a unique equilateral triangle, so in the moduli space $M$ there is a unique point $p_{eq}$ which is the isomorphism class of equilateral triangles. So if the universal family exists, then the fibre $ \pi^{-1}(p_{eq})$ should be an actual equilateral triangle.

> And what does it mean to say that the family doesn't contain some other family?

To say that the universal family $\pi: U \rightarrow M$ contains every other family means that, for any family of triangles $: \phi: T \rightarrow Y$, there is a map $f: Y \rightarrow M$ such that the pullback family $U \times_f Y \rightarrow Y$ is isomorphic to $ T \rightarrow Y$. If you don't know about pullbacks don't worry the important point is that this would imply that for any $y \in Y$, the triangle $\phi^{-1}(y)$ is isomorphic to the triangle $\pi^{-1}(f(y))$. In particular if all the triangles in the family $T$ are isomorphic (as in the example in the link) then we would have to have $f: Y \rightarrow M$ being a constant map. But pulling back via a constant map always gives a *trivial* family $\Delta \times Y$ (for some fixed triangle \Delta)$. In the example the "twisted" family over the circle is not trivial, and that contradicts the existence of the universal family.